# How do I fix Lightbox2 problems using $.noConflict()?

Tags: javascript, drupal, picasa, lightbox2

I've imported images to my site. I want to open these images with lightbox2. I've installed the lightbox2-drupalmodule and that works on my frontpage (www.chirowijkoersel.be), but it doesn't work on the pages where I imported images.

Lightbox does work with Opera. I've also noticed that the lightbox2-module adds a class to the images in Opera and on the frontpage with every other browser.

Links:

- [Images page](http://www.chirowijkoersel.be/fotoalbum/bivak-2011-grobbendonk-bezoekdag)
- [Frontpage](http://www.chirowijkoersel.be/)

Edit:
I've done some research, and I think the problem is caused by the multiple use of $. I can solve this by using  $.noConflict(). But where do I need to put this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap of you javascript, and use self invoking functions

```
(function($){

      /// Your page code here
      // Here you can use $ 
      // We are passing jquery as $ to this self invoking function.
})(jquery)
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be javascript conflicts ?

Comment: Could be, my knowledge of javascript is quite limited. Any sugestions to solve it?

Comment: There is also a 'sponsors'-block on my frontpage, that block works with every browser except Opera.

Answer (score 0):

You would put the $.noConflict() inside a script tag, right after you import jQuery. So if you have something like:

```
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
```

already, you'd just do:

```
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script>$.noConflict();</script>
```

Hope that helps.